# Flutter 2 + InAppWebView + firebase_messaging, how to pass the Url on 'onMessageOpenedApp'?

Tags: flutter, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

### pubspec.yml - dependencies

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+21
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.1
```

### FCM sample data(firebase console)

```
{
  title: 'text'
  body: 'text body'
  data: {
    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
    url: 'https://customurl.com'
  }
}
```

### main.dart

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ...

  String webViewUrl = "https://baseurl.com/";

  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ...

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('# onMessage Listen message title:  ${message.notification?.title}');
      print('# onMessage Listen message body:  ${message.notification?.body}');
      print('# onMessage Listen message dataUrl:  ${message.data['url']}');

      // How to pass url to webView
      // below code is not work.
      if (message.data['url'] != null) {
        setState(() {
          this.url = message.data['url'];
        });
      }
    });

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                key: webViewKey,
                
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(webViewUrl)),

                initialOptions: options,
                pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  webViewController = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url.toString();
                    urlController.text = this.url;
                  });
                },
...
```

### log with click push notification & opened app

```
I/flutter (16128): # onMessage Listen message title:  text
I/flutter (16128): # onMessage Listen message body:  text body
I/flutter (16128): # onMessage Listen message dataUrl:  https://customurl.com
```

### Current Results (Android, not yet test in iOS)

- Load WebView BaseUrl (O)
- Receive FCM foreground (O)
- Receive FCM background (O)
- onMessageOpenedApp (O)
- onMessageOpenedApp => customUrl (X)

### Question

How do I move the webView to the url address received from FCM when the push notification is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself.

change code to

```
if (message.data['url'] != null) {
    setState(() {
      webViewController?.loadUrl(
          urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(message.data['url'])));
    });
}
```

from

```
if (message.data['url'] != null) {
    setState(() {
      this.url = message.data['url'];
    });
}
```